# Image carousel not working with overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css

There is something i cannot understand in the below example:

consider two cases below:

1. I removed `<div class="carousel">`. In the CSS under when overflow: hidden is commented (in image-container) the transform: translateX(-100%); works fine and displays the 2nd image. But when overflow:hidden is enabled everything goes away.
2. when `<div class="carousel">` is inserted everything works fine.

Please help me to understand the issue. I will extra information if needed.

```css
.carousel {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}

.image-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-container {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

img {
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!-- <div class="carousel"> -->
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500.png?text=nature-1" alt="" class="one">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500.png?text=nature-2" alt="" class="two">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500.png?text=nature-3" alt="" class="three">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500.png?text=nature-4" alt="" class="four">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500.png?text=nature-5" alt="" class="five">
</div>
<!-- </div> -->
```

Comment: I have taken images from pexels (500px by 500px). they are in my computer. can you please look into my problem by considering any image. I don't know how to add image from placeholder.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `overflow:hidden` on the image-container, any image outside of it's dimensions should be hidden. Shifting the container to the side with `transform:translateX(-100%)` does not change this. The first image would still be visible in the image-container but the whole image container has been shifted out of view.

You could get rid of the outer div by styling `.image-container>*{transform:translateX(-100%)}` to shift the images themselves within the image container instead of shifting the container. This might lead to slightly more graphics processing overhead for the page as it transforms each image instead of the one container of images, but I can't imagine that this would actually be noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to remove .carousel. IMO it should wrap your .image-container and .image-container should not have `overflow: hidden`. Try to add borders to .carousel - `border: 1px solid red;` and see where your .image-container is relative to .carousel.